# MailChimp MergeTags CSS/HTML - Change color depending on character in string

Tags: css, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm sending daily newsletters with Mailchimp and use "merge tags" extensively. I fill the defaults of the merge tags with a python script via API.

I add a bar with the stock market moves of yesterday - the data I have in python.
I struggle with visualization.
Currently, everything is in default text color, it would be much nicer if the +xx% or  -xx% would be green/red accordingly. Even the hole string/merge tag could be recolored for me, but I'm not advanced in CSS and I don't know how to do that in HTML. Javascript seems to be strongly discouraged (blocked) to be used with Mailchimp mails.
https://mailchimp.com/help/css-in-html-email/

Example:
[Picture with the bar on https://www.bloomberg.com/europe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMYbd.png)

MergeTag / String:

- xxx 2000 +0.35%
- yyyy 27000 -0.04%
- zzzz 1234 +0.00%

Some more explanation:
MailChimp uses  "merge tags" (the interchangeable string I'm talking about) that I can adjust to my/our needs. This gets "translated" into the proper text when the MailChimp newsletter is sent and I just update the string externally. So the needed CSS "script" is always the same but I adjust the external string to my needs. And so I'd like to enter the string and then depending on what is in the string (+ or -) it should change the color of the percentage value.
So the input will be the string as a so-called "merge tag" in MailChimp. This merge tag is put in the MailChimp editor (like this: *|MERGETAG|*) and then this gets "translated" into the string that I dynamically define with python and then the CSS script (?) should change the color

Comment: Have you tried putting the merge tag inside some html, like a span with some styling? `<span style="color: red;">|YOURTAG|</span>`. That's all I got.

Comment: Sure, changing the color is possible. I want to change the color conditionally. If there is a - in the string then it sounds be red, if there is a +, the string part should be green.